# Why does my program freeze when timer_Tick code runs?

Tags: c#

My program is made to auto open another program when ROBLOX opens. I know that's weird but helpful to me. Once the program is open, my buttons and everything work fine. Once I enable it, and open ROBLOX, the application breaks until ROBLOX is closed. Just freezes, no errors. Doesn't open the other application either. Please help!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProtoSmasher_Auto_Opener
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string path;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!File.Exists(@"c:\PSAutoStart\path.proto"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It seems like this is your first time running. Please make sure File Manager is closed for your first run.", "Notice");
            }
            if (File.Exists(@"c:\PSAutoStart\path.proto"))
            {
                string lastPath;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\PSAutoStart\path.proto"))
                {
                    lastPath = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
                textBox1.Text = lastPath;
                path = lastPath;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button1.BackColor != System.Drawing.Color.Red)
            {
                if(textBox1.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please click browse and locate ProtoSmasher to activate.", "Error");
                }
                else
                {
                    button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    button1.Text = "Deactivate";
                    timer1.Start();
                }
            }
            else
            {      
                button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                button1.Text = "Activate";
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Filter = "ProtoSmasher (*.exe)|*.exe";
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = fileDialog.FileName;
                if (!File.Exists(@"c:\PSAutoStart\path.proto"))
                {
                    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\PSAutoStart");
                    try
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2 * 1000);
                        StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"c:\PSAutoStart\path.proto");
                        sw.WriteLine(path);
                        textBox1.Text = path;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Didn't I tell you to close your file manager first?", "Error");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"c:\PSAutoStart\path.proto"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(path);
                    }
                    textBox1.Text = path;
                }
            }

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] roblox = Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta");
            if (roblox.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Process.Start(textBox1.Text);
                    stillRunning.Start(); //to keep from spamming open
                    timer1.Stop(); 
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong: " + ex, "Error");
                }
            }
        }

        private void stillRunning_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] roblox = Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta");
            if(roblox.Length > 0)
            { }
            else
            {
                timer1.Start();
                stillRunning.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something shy of 1 dozen timers in .NET. Wich one is that? Asuming it is the WindowsForms Timer: That one runs in the main thread. You need to use some form of actually multitasking here. For beginners, I advise for BackgroundWorkers in WindowsForm.

Comment: I'm familiar with c# but not really good at it. Is there a documentation anywhere about BackgroundWorkers and how they work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This might also be worth a read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is something just shy of a dozen timers in .NET. I am going to asume it is the WindowsForms Timer:

Only one piece of code can run per Thread. And the WindowsForms timer runs in the GUI thread. Timers varry a lot in this regard, but then you also might have to deal with CrossThread saftey. I think you want to add some explicit multitasking into the mix.

Multitasking is a very tricky are to learn. My usual advice for learning it is using the BackgroundWorker in a WindowsForms application. You would not want to be caught with it in production code, but it is a very good set "training wheels". I also have some old example on how to use it:

```
#region Primenumbers
private void btnPrimStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        //Prepare ProgressBar and Textbox
        int temp = (int)nudPrim.Value;
        pgbPrim.Maximum = temp;
        tbPrim.Text = "";

        //Start processing
        bgwPrim.RunWorkerAsync(temp);
    }
}

private void btnPrimCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        bgwPrim.CancelAsync();
    }
}

private void bgwPrim_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int highestToCheck = (int)e.Argument;
    //Get a reference to the BackgroundWorker running this code
    //for Progress Updates and Cancelation checking
    BackgroundWorker thisWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    //Create the list that stores the results and is returned by DoWork
    List<int> Primes = new List<int>();


    //Check all uneven numbers between 1 and whatever the user choose as upper limit
    for(int PrimeCandidate=1; PrimeCandidate < highestToCheck; PrimeCandidate+=2)
    {
        //Report progress
        thisWorker.ReportProgress(PrimeCandidate);
        bool isNoPrime = false;

        //Check if the Cancelation was requested during the last loop
        if (thisWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            //Tell the Backgroundworker you are canceling and exit the for-loop
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }

        //Determin if this is a Prime Number
        for (int j = 3; j < PrimeCandidate && !isNoPrime; j += 2)
        {
            if (PrimeCandidate % j == 0)
                isNoPrime = true;
        }

        if (!isNoPrime)
            Primes.Add(PrimeCandidate);
    }

    //Tell the progress bar you are finished
    thisWorker.ReportProgress(highestToCheck);

    //Save Return Value
    e.Result = Primes.ToArray();
}

private void bgwPrim_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void bgwPrim_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = pgbPrim.Maximum;
    this.Refresh();

    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        //Show the Result
        int[] Primes = (int[])e.Result;

        StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (int Prim in Primes)
        {
            sbOutput.Append(Prim.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        tbPrim.Text = sbOutput.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        tbPrim.Text = "Operation canceled by user or Exception";
    }
}
#endregion
```

However I am a bit uncertain what your programm even does. Getting all the processes with a specific string and force-closing them?

Comment: No, its not force closing any. Basically when ROBLOX opens, the program should detect it. Once detected, it will open another application and stop the timer so it doesn't spam open the application. The second timer makes sure ROBLOX is still running and when it's not, start the timer again to detect ROBLOX.

Comment: @Zeridiant that sounds like a Deamon that does not need a UI, and thus can lock it's main thread with polling. Of coruse it needs a way to interrupt the polling, if cancelation is requested. Maybe even a Windows Service. | It is possible to add Deamon functionality to any programm, but then you will always need an extra thread for that work.

Comment: @Zeridiant However usually the best way to react to something, is to be the one starting it in the first place. If you need a desktop link, DRM/Updater systems like Steam or Epic use a trick to be the starter and still have a desktop Icon: A Web-Link. You can set up Programms to be registerd to certain protocolls, including custom ones like "steam:" and "com.epicgames.launcher:". Add some single instance mechanic with relaying requests to the running instance and you should be fine.